# Create new array containing objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wish to create a new array that contains objects from another Object

This was my try:

```
var obj =  {
    a:{},
    b:{}
}

var arr = new Array().concat(obj,[]);
```

Sadly, this is returning an array like this:

```
Array[1]
0: Object
    a: Object
    b: Object
```

The desired array, however, should look like this:

```
Array[2]
    0: Object
        a: Object
    1: Object
        b: Object
```

How could i achieve that in the shortest possible way, without having to loop the object?

Comment: Could you show what the desired end result should look like?

Comment: Do you mean you want `var arr = [obj.a, obj.b];` ?

Comment: Well, the question says you want `[{a: obj.a}, {b: obj.b}]`.

Comment: @user2422960 the syntax I posted should do the trick. Unless a and b are just examples and you want to dynamically retrieve all properties of some object, in which case I'd use the `for` `in` loop and the `hasOwnProperty` function to add all members to an array. Unless what you want is actually what @Juhana mentioned.

Comment: "without having to loop the object" --- what is the *technical* reason for avoiding explicit loops in the code?

Comment: There's no way to guarantee the order in the resulting array, because objects don't have to remember the order of their properties. So unless you're OK with getting `[{ b: {} }, { a: {} }]`, it can't be done.

Comment: Could you explain what problem you're trying to solve by turning the object into an array? This sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example without explicit loops:

```
var r = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    var o = {};
    o[key] = this[key];
    return o;
}, obj);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zNh3G/